# YouTube API on the Fragment - Error - YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player

Tags: android, youtube-api

Below is my Activity layout XML

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context="com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                       android:id="@+id/activity_workout_view_pager"
                                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                       android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                                       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>    


</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my fragment layout XML, which gets displayed in ViewPager in above activity .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/customborder"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <-- youtube player will be displayed here -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_layout"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
         />

 </LinearLayout>
```

The above activity / fragment displayed youtube player and played the video for only 1 sec , and then displayed below error

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. 
The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{33c5dbf VFED..... ......ID 0,112-720,1184 #7f08001a app:id/activity_workout_view_pager}. 

The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 740, top: 60, right: -460, bottom: 572 (these should all be positive).
```

As per my understanding this issue is related to layout of activity / fragment , any idea how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You cannot have any view that covers the youtube player fragment. Any view overlay over youtube fragment instance which you inflate would cause the video to stop playing after a specified time.

Comment: Ok , but can you specify what needs to be modified to fix this issue ,

Comment: I think your `FrameLayout ` might be covering `YoutubeFragment`.

Comment: Also have height and width of `LinearLayout ` as `match_parent`.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the `ViewPager` as stated in the logs `activity_workout_view_pager`, There seems to be something wrong with the right-side edge of the ViewPager: it is in negative (also stated in log for both ViewPager and `YouTubePlayerView`). I've never used YouTubePlayer inside a ViewPager but I think the issue is that somehow the playback is starting when the view is not completely shown to user i.e. hidden out of screen bounds.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is when played during animated transition and the view is not completely visible. You could easily test that by binding playback to click.